# Check broken images on page

Tags: javascript, broken-image

How do I find all broken images on page?
I need to find all broken images on page. But the problem is that my script dynamically downloaded on customer page from another domain. When I run my script on the page, I don't know if images is already downloaded or they are still in download process. I do the following:

```
if (!img.complete) {
    img.onerror = function () { 
        // broken image 
    }
} else {
    if (img.naturalHeight === 0 && img.naturalWidth === 0) {
        // broken image 
    }
}
```

But for img.complete, IE returns 'false' not only when images are still in the process of downloading, but even if images are broken. So I need to distinguish between these two cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have direct access to the page"?

Comment: My script is download on the page dinamically

Comment: Сlarified question

Comment: I think you should be able to make that distinction by waiting until everything has loaded before testing (using window.onload)

Comment: This solution does not suitable for my case. Markup and images can be loaded even after onload event (especially if client use react or angular framework).